# Multiple inputs in while loops?

Tags: python, input, while-loop

How can i add all the lines of the input to the list?

```
N, L, K = [int(x) for x in input('Évek száma, max életkor, ivarérettség: ').split()]
a = 1
while a<=L:
    i = input('I. sorban I éves nyulak száma: ')
    nyulak = []
    nyulak.append(i)
    a = a+1

print(nyulak)
```

This way it adds only the last line like:

```
Évek száma, max életkor, ivarérettség: 10 2 3
I. sorban I éves nyulak száma: 2
I. sorban I éves nyulak száma: 8
['8']
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad english :/

Comment: Move `nyulak = []` to outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

```py
N, L, K = [int(x) for x in input('Évek száma, max életkor, ivarérettség: ').split()]
a = 1
nyulak = [] # Declare your list here
while a<=L:
    i = input('I. sorban I éves nyulak száma: ')
    nyulak.append(i)
    a = a+1

print(nyulak)
```